# I set time to wrong time zone, how do I change it? (Debian)

Tags: debian, timezone

I am on Debian and have used the dpkg-reconfigure tzdata command, however it changed the universal time and not the local time. My clock on xfce still displays the wrong time. Right after setting the right time it displays this:

Current default time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
Local time is now:      Sun Jan 17 04:50:23 PST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Sun Jan 17 12:50:23 UTC 2016.

My time is 4:50 am

It seems to have the correct timezone, but it is eight hours off :(

Comment: What timezone are you in? To which timezone did you set the system? What was it before? What time is it for you, and what time does your system say it is? Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: 4:53 is my time.

Comment: It sounds like you now have the timezone set correctly, but the actual system clock is off by 8 hours. Run `ntpd` to set the system clock automatically and you won't have to worry about this. Failing that, set the system clock to the correct time manually or with `ntpdate` or `rdate`.

Comment: It seems like the common conflict between Linux and Windows about time. [Windows wants the hardware time to be local, Linux expect the hardware to be UTC.](http://www.howtogeek.com/211144/how-to-get-windows-and-linux-clocks-to-display-the-correct-and-matching-time-dual-boot/?PageSpeed=noscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your clock to the correct time. Right now it's 2100 UTC, so in Los Angeles it should be 1pm (1300 hours).

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: I set my time with the date command it works now. :p

Comment: Excellent. I was just trying to find out how to set it using the XFCE GUI